# Delayed number boxes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've noticed that the number input has a delay in firing the onChange event if you press the up/down arrow buttons inside the box.

On other browsers like Mac Safari and Firefox, the onChange event is called immediately.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/yyfvv0vg/

```
<input type="number" max="9999" min="1" onchange="change()"/>
<div></div>

function change()
{
    $("div").html($("input").val());
}
```

Is there a way to force it to update immediately, or is it just a fact of life that I have to deal with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `onchange` event try using `onmouseup` it will work.

It seems like while you put the **cursor over the arrows** in **chrome**, the data is updated until you **move the cursor out of the arrows**, try using the up and down keywords and you will see what I'm telling you, the data is inmediatly updated.